# How to show the set $\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,\bar{K})$ of all $K$-embeddings of $L$ is partitioned into $m$ equivalence classes of $d$ elements each?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $L|K$ be a finite separable extension. Denote the algebraic closure of $K$ by $\bar K$.

$\forall x\in L$, denote $d=[L:K(x)]$ and $m=[K(x):K]$.

How to show the set $\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,\bar{K})$ of all $K$-embeddings of $L$ is partitioned by the equivalence relation $$\sigma\sim \tau \Longleftrightarrow \sigma x=\tau x$$ into $m$ equivalence classes of $d$ elements each?

Comment: The question has been posted also on MathOverflow: [How to show the set $\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,\bar{K})$ of all $K$-embeddings of $L$ is partitioned into $m$ equivalence classes of $d$ elements each?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312934) I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) provides a very reasonable advice on cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of this via Galois theory, is that if you take $F$ to be the Galois closure of $L$ over $K$, then

1. $Hom_K(L, \overline{K}) \cong Hom_K(L, F) \cong Gal(F/K) / Gal(F/L)$
2. The partition you are talking about is really the map
   $$ Hom_K(L, F) \stackrel{res}{\longrightarrow} Hom_K(K(x), F)$$
   So if you think from the perspective of group theory, it's really the quotient map
   $$ Gal(F/K) / Gal(F/L) \to Gal(F/K) / Gal(F/K(x))$$
   So the size of each equivalence class being equal really comes from all cosets have the same size.

Comment: Where can I find the relative theorems to deduce the above conclusions you've given?

Comment: Any textbook on Galois theory should do. I'm not sure which part above is not clear - if you state that more clearly I may try to find some reference

Comment: I even can't find the notion "Galois closure" in GTM 101 or GTM 167. Do the two books have the notion "Galois closure"?

Comment: I don't have them with me now, I am not sure. One possibility is that you may be working in the realm of separable extensions, in which case we only need to care about normality - so look for normal closure as well

Answer (score 0):

I guess because the degree of the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $x$ over $K$ is $m$, then $p(x)$ has $m$ different roots $a_1,\cdots,a_m$ in $\bar K$, we can let $\sigma x=a_i(i=1,\cdots,m)$. But How to show there exist $d$ different $K$-embeddings sending $x$ to $a_i$ for each $i$?

Comment: 一个很直接的方式是证明对有限可分扩张，嵌入到代数闭包的总可能性跟扩张的次数一致（更一般地，对未必可分的扩张则跟扩张的 *可分次数*一致；这个在比较深入地讲解伽罗瓦理论的书里都会有，可能比如Lang的*代数*之类的吧）。这样你所叙述的结果只不过是扩张次数之可乘性的简单推论而已（你这里所涉及的扩张都是可分的）！